# How to add dashes in jQuery options with multiple values

Tags: jquery

I have a POS system and I get customer data in three fields. `Name`, `Email`, and `Mobile`.

Let's suppose the values are:

```
Name = Owais
Email = owais@gmail.com
Mobile = 03214834289
```

I am loading this in somewhere with this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.categories.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.categories[i];       
    var cust_id     = counter.cust_id;
    var cust_name   = counter.cust_name;
    var cust_emai   = counter.cust_email;
    var cust_mobile = counter.cust_mobile;

    option = document.createElement( 'option' );
    option.value = cust_id;
    option.text = cust_name + cust_email + cust_mobile;
    select.add( option );
}
```

The output is:

[image]

I want the output show like this

```
Owais - owais@gmail.com - 03214834289
```

How I add dashes in output ?

Comment: Concatenate them to the string you're already building: `cust_name + ' -
 ' + cust_email +  ' -
 ' + cust_mobile;`

Comment: just replace the instr `option.text = cust_name +" - "+cust_email +" - "+ cust_mobile;`

Comment: Thanks :) it is working.
Stackoverflow is the best

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to set option.text to

```
cust_name + " - " + cust_email + " - " + cust_mobile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like This way :

```
 option = document.createElement( 'option' );
 option.value = cust_id;
 option.text = cust_name + " - " + cust_email + " - " + cust_mobile;
 select.add( option );
```